# Remove Same Column from Multiple Dataframes in R

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to remove the same column "col3" from multiple dataframes "df1" and "df2" in R using the below code but I do not know how to reassign the result of the lapply function to the dataframes. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:4), col2 = c("A","B","C","D"), col3 = c("H","I","J","K"))
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c(11:14), col2 = c("L","M","N","O"), col3 = c("W","X","Y","Z"))
list_dfs <- list(df1,df2)

lapply(list_dfs, function(x) x[!(names(x) %in% c("col3"))])
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `select` with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
list_dfs2 <- map(list_dfs, ~ .x %>%
                                select(-col3))
```

Or without anonymous function

```
list_dfs2 <- map(list_dfs, dplyr::select, -col3)
```

---

or with `lapply` and `subset`

```
list_dfs2 <- lapply(list_dfs, subset, select = -col3)
list_dfs2
#[[1]]
#  col1 col2
#1    1    A
#2    2    B
#3    3    C
#4    4    D

#[[2]]
#  col1 col2
#1   11    L
#2   12    M
#3   13    N
#4   14    O
```

It is better to keep the datasets in a `list` and not create multiple datasets in the global environment

---

We can `mget` to create named `list` and update the original datasets with `list2env`

```
list2env(lapply(mget(paste0('df', 1:2)), subset, select = -col3), .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or another simple option is `assign` with a `for` loop

```
for(df in paste0('df', 1:2)) assign(df, subset(get(df), select = -col3))
df1
#  col1 col2
#1    1    A
#2    2    B
#3    3    C
#4    4    D

df2
#  col1 col2
#1   11    L
#2   12    M
#3   13    N
#4   14    O
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to assign the subsetted result back to original dataframes, create a named list using :

```
list_dfs <- list(df1 = df1,df2 = df2)
#OR
#list_dfs <- dplyr::lst(df1, df2)
```

Perform the subset operation

```
list_dfs <- lapply(list_dfs, function(x) x[names(x) != "col3"])
```

Assign the result back to original dataframes using  `list2env`

```
list2env(list_dfs, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code to drop the columns is fine - you need to assign the result. `list_dfs <- lapply(...)`. In R, almost always, if you don't use `<-` or `=` for assignment, nothing changes.